# Implement collision detection by extendung the Rectangle class to use its contains and intersects methods

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection, java-2d

I would like to know if this is a good idea that to implement simple 2D collision detection of rectangles as follows:

1. Make my own Collision detection class that extends Rectangle class.
2. Then when instantiating that object doing something such as `Collision col = new Rectangle();` <- Should I do that or is that something that should be avoided? I am aware that I **'can'** but *should* I?
3. I want to extend Rectangle class because of the `contains()` and `intersects()` methods; should I be doing that or should I be doing something else for 2D collision detection in Java?

Comment: Assertion 2 is wrong; you similarly wouldn't make Square extend Rectangle and declare Square s = new Rectangle(), right?

Comment: That is why it is polymorphic. Bounding rectangles on 2D objects to detect collisions.

Comment: You can't assign an object of a super-type to a reference of a sub-type.  The types are incompatible.  `Rectangle col=new Collision()`, sure, but not `Collision col=new Rectangle()`.

Comment: Yes I had it backwards; thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily extend `Rectangle`

```
class CollidableRectangle extends Rectangle
{
  public boolean isCollidingWith(Rectangle otherRect)
  {
    //check collision
  }

  // return all collisions
  public List<CollidableRectangle> getCollisions(List<Rectangle)
  {
    // code
  }
}
```

then you would use it like:

```
CollidableRectangle r1 = new CollidableRectangle();
CollidableRectangle r2 = new CollidableRectangle();

r1.isCollidingWith(r2);

//and so on
```

As noted in comments I didn't use a `Collision` class. Usually you need it because you are also interested in collision parameters like **depth** or **colliding plane** so you would have something like:

```
class Collision
{
   CollidableRectangle first, second;
   float depth;
   Line2D collidingLine;
}
```

and the method would return a list of collisions:

```
public List<Collision> getCollisions(List<Rectangle) { ... }
```

Comment: About "obscenely confusing code," notice that Jack called his class CollidableRectangle instead of Collision; it's fairly clear that a CollidableRectangle is a kind of Rectangle, but it's not clear that a Collision is a kind of Rectangle.

Comment: good example, although I don't like the getCollisions method (name), as you are not returning collisions

Comment: Yes, in a ready example you would have your own __Collision__ class, also if it implies some overhead (maybe many object allocations) but usually you need to store some collision data (example: the depth of the collision or the colliding plane/point)

Answer (score 7):

There is not a `is-a` relation between a Collision and a Rectangle, a collision is not a rectangle. A collision domain may have rectangles which suggests that you use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Answer (score 0):

What about making it unrelated to Rectangle in the first place?  Make a new, standalone Collision module and handle any different types you want.

(I don't know Java, sorry for any issues here)

```
class Collision
{
   public boolean BetweenRectangles(Rectangle a, Rectangle b)
   {
   }

   public boolean BetweenCircles(Circle a, Circle b)
   {
   }

   public boolean RectangleToCircle(Rectangle r, Circle c)
   {
   }

   public boolean MyCrazyShapeToRectangle(MyCrazyShape mcs, Rectangle r)
   {
   }
}
```

IMHO it doesn't really make sense to make a collision out of a rectangle because a collision is an orthogonal concept to the rectangle, and jamming them together needlessly constrains your future options.  The key thing to realize is that you don't really need a collision object, per se, these functions are procedural by nature (does Java have something like C++'s 'static' modifier for class-scope member functions?).  The collision itself isn't a property of either of the participants of a collision.